# gcc / make - creating make files for creating assembly and linking

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile

To perform an experiment I want to modify the assembly code of the OpenWRT Project (by inserting NOPs between the regular, meaningful code).
Thous I need to create the assembly files (.s files) by compiling with gcc's -S flag in the first run, execute a shell script modifying the assembly files and call the linker in the third step to create the executable binaries. Beside step 2, is there a way to accomplish steps 1 & 3 by an appropriate make file modification/configuration, i.e. create one make file for compiling (creating .s files) and another to conduct linking?

Thanks for enlightenment &
Happy a new year! :)

Answer (score 1):

use this syntax:

```
target [target...] : [dependent ....]
     [ command ...]
```

example:

```
 %.S: %.c
      $(CC) -S $@ -c $<
 %.o: %.S
      $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

which means to build the target foo.o make should build foo.S and for foo.S build foo.c
$@ means target name
$< means targets first dependency

Comment: I'd recommend `.s` for compiler-output asm.  Only use `.S` for hand-written asm sources.  (Unless the OP's script-driven modifications add anything that needs the C preprocessor).

Comment: I would actually suggest to produce custom extension like .s_orig, then add another rule %.s : %.s_orig  which will run the script adding the nops (if it can be done with script), and the final rule for %.o : %.s as in answer. This way the makefile will cover all steps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot your answers! But, what does parameter '-@' mean (did you mean '$@', I can't find '-@' on the entire man page..).

Comment: sorry it was a typo